# Converting Signature to Image PHP

Tags: php

**Background**

I am updating a PHP application from 5.3 to 7. currently I am targeting 5.6
to start with.

There is a section of the app which convert a signature to a image. When that file runs I get this error.

**Error**

> **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in **signature-to-image.php** on
>   line **43**

This is the line it references in the error.

**Code**

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier'], $options['imageSize'][1] * $options['drawMultiplier']);
```

**Question**

Could anyone clarify the problem here?

I was thinking this has to do with a server configuration and not a version of PHP problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
array(5) {
  ["imageSize"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(373)
    [1]=>
    int(95)
  }
  ["bgColour"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(255)
    [1]=>
    int(255)
    [2]=>
    int(255)
  }
  ["penWidth"]=>
  int(2)
  ["penColour"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["drawMultiplier"]=>
  int(12)
}
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
```

Comment: In my experience, newer PHP versions tend to use *less* memory, not more. Are you setting `memory_limit` explicitly or relying on system default?

Comment: A 32Mb limit is pretty small. Your 5.3 server most likely has a higher setting.

Comment: More often than not "Allowed memory size of [BIG number] exhausted (tried to allocate [SMALL number])" usually means that you have an infinite loop somewhere, or are just doing too much without freeing memory. Are you remembering to call `imagedestroy` to free the memory after you're done with an image resource?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I use a 32M limit on my rather big online game, and I have not come close to hitting it except when I make an error in the code...

Comment: Thanks for your input. This app is large and I am digging through it one error at a time. I was trying to get someone else's feedback to help me track it down. Because I did not write it. I am looking to see if memory_limit is set explicitly. But I do not think it is from what I have seen. And I did not want to just jack up the memory limit in case there was a problem so I could fix the problem not just bandage it.

Comment: please `var_dump($options)` so we can see how large of an image you a creating. Also you can up your memory limit with `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` as working with images takes a lot of memory,

Comment: OK on it right now. THanks everyone

Comment: Please see the bottom of my question. I added the output from var_dump

Comment: The actual image size you are creating is 4476px x 1140px if you do the math (4476 * 1140 * 32) is 163284480 bytes -> 164M for your `memory_limit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `php` script needs more memory than the one specified on the **php.ini** `memory_limit` setting.

You've 2 options:

1 - Edit the **php.ini** `memory_limit` setting to a higher value and restart `apache`.

2 -  Add the following to your script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M') # try several values until you find the appropriate one, no more no less.
```

Comment: Yes I appreciate you. But the point to this was that if there is a problem with the size I do not just increase the size limit and ignore the problem. I do realize I can up the memory limit but is that a abnormal size for a signature? I worry because I am migrating to a new version of PHP and I would think it should not be so high.

Comment: Sure, pay attention to @niet-the-dark-absol comment.

Comment: @wuno Have you tried increasing the memory to, lets say, 64M? if so, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your help Pedro